# Exclude Entities from SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Can someone tell me how to exclude some entity from context before saving changes.

For Example i have 2 entities Actions and Users and i want to save only users?

Comment: You say you want to save only `User` entities, but have there been any changes to attached `Action` entities? If not you shouldn't worry for nothing will be saved. Could you post some code on how you modify these entities?

Comment: I changed both entities, but i want to save only User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you changed an Action and you don't want to modify it you can either detach it from context or set it as unchanged (that is like hack).

Detaching entity:

```
context.Detach(action);
```

Setting state to unchanged:

```
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(action, EntityState.Unchanged);
```

Be aware that if you also changed relation between Action and User you will also need to reaset state of the relation by calling `ObjectStateManager.ChangeRelationshipState`.

Anyway you are doing something wrong because this situation should not happen. You should always modify only entities you want to save. If for any reason you need to modify only part of them your approach with clonning entities and modify them in other context is correct. Context is unit of work. You should modify only entities which are part of the same business transaction.

Comment: Ok, thanks i solved this with cloning. You right when you said that this solution shouldn't happen, i was doing something wrong, but cloning helps.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible as the `SaveChanges` method works on context level, not entity level.

Comment: Can i somehow change state of some object to unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

Well the best option would be not to modify the entities unless you really mean to change them.  However you can change their state.  The book Programming Entity Framework has details on this.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by creating copy of entities Action with all child's (deep copy), and when i changed them i worked on the copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the state of the changed objects (of type `Action` in your case) to "Unchanged" using the `ObjectStateManager` like so:

```
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(actionObject, EntityState.Unchanged);
```

I hope this helps :)

ps: you can get the list of modified objects using this:

```
var modifiedActions = context.Actions.Where(a=>a.EntityState!=EntityState.Unchanged);
```